# Does LeBlanc's second cast on her W proc SpellBlade (Lich Bane)?

Tags: league-of-legends

The title says it all.

For example:

- LeBlanc stands around near an Ashe.
- LeBlanc W's towards the Ashe.
- LeBlanc auto-attacks the Ashe and activates Spellblade.
- LeBlanc quickly W's back to her original spot.
- LeBlanc auto-attacks the Ashe.

Does LeBlanc get the buff when she W's the second time?

Comment: I dont think it would, but even if it did, Spellblade has a 2 second cooldown, so you'd have to wait.

Comment: RIP old awesome Lich Bane ;-;

Comment: Well, Spellblade has a 2 second cooldown, while LeBlanc's W can be used a second time for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the second cast of Distortion doesn't trigger Lich Bane to empower your next auto attack.

Video reference:

Watch the Spellblade buff on Leblanc's buff bar - you may need to watch it a few times. When you see the Spellblade buff your next auto attack is empowered, and the buff lasts for a number of seconds before you lose the empowered attack (you can see a countdown effect).

Every additional ability used *without* making an empowered attack refreshes the Spellblade  buff. This means that if the Spellblade buff is not refreshed by using an ability, then that ability does not activate Spellblade.

If you watch the video, you can see Leblanc jump forward with Distortion, granting her the Spellblade buff from Sheen. When she uses Sigil of Silence shortly after, the buff is refreshed. However, when she returns by re-activating Distortion, the buff is not refreshed.

Since the buff isn't refreshed on the second cast of Distortion, the second cast of Distortion will not activate Lich Bane. I would safely guess that this also applies to the second cast of Mimic: Distortion.

Comment: Lol, your name is the answer.